# Could not initialize AdView: Required XML attribute "adUnitId" missing

Tags: xml, admob

I am trying to add advertise to my app . While trying to run  it is giving error:

> Could not initialize AdView: Required XML attribute "adUnitId"
>   missing.

Although I have given AdMob site generated `adUnitId`.

My XML file is following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#008080" >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text100"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:text="Tal/Jathi" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text101"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Three" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text102"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Four" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text103"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Five" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text104"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Seven" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text105"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nine" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Dhruv" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Mattya" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Roopaka" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Jampa" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button19"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Triputa" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button22"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button23"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button24"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button25"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text6"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Ata" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button26"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button27"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button28"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button29"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button30"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text7"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Eka" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button31"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button32"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button33"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button34"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button35"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shapemain" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textbit1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textbit2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textbit3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textbit4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
 <com.google.ads.AdView 
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"  
            ads.adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7782388826013394/3278126866"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
             > 
             </com.google.ads.AdView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tempo" >
        </TextView>
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100" >
        </SeekBar>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonstop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/shapemain"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="STOP" />

    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice there is a typo in your xml it says `ads.adUnitId`. It needs to be `ads:adUnitId` (colon)

Comment: Thanks Ivo Beckers , That was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the XML namespace incorrectly.
It should be:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

if you are using Google Play Services version of Admob or

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads
```

`if you are using Admob-6.4.1 or earlier which it looks like you are.

Comment: if i use xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" istead of  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"  then it is showing error no resource found for adSize,adUnitId,testdevice.so what should i do.

Comment: I think he's using the old admob jar instead of via google play services. He's using  "<com.google.ads.AdView" so he must maintain the namespace " xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" @Arunima, are you using the admob jar in the lib folder?